# Cannot debug Rust code using LLDB in VS Code: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust, lldb

I want to debug Rust with VS Code. I have installed LLDB 6.0.0 and Rust 1.27.1 but I can't debug Rust code with LLDB:

```
Display settings: variable format=auto, show disassembly=auto, numeric pointer values=off, container summaries=on.
Internal debugger error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kwebi/.vscode/extensions/vadimcn.vscode-lldb-0.8.9/adapter/debugsession.py", line 1365, in handle_message
    result = handler(args)
  File "/home/kwebi/.vscode/extensions/vadimcn.vscode-lldb-0.8.9/adapter/debugsession.py", line 385, in DEBUG_setBreakpoints
    file_id = os.path.normcase(from_lldb_str(source.get('path')))
  File "/home/kwebi/.vscode/extensions/vadimcn.vscode-lldb-0.8.9/adapter/__init__.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    from_lldb_str = lambda s: s.decode('utf8', 'replace')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 12-13: ordinal not in range(128)
```